# Resetting the column filters of HTML table on click

Tags: jquery, html, filter, tableview, html-table

I am using column filter jquery for filtering html table columns.

Here is the javascript: http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/729/jQuery-Table-Column-Filters

You can see the demo here: http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/729/jQuery-Table-Column-Filters

This javascript filters the table columns on typing in the text boxes appearing in the table head.

Is there any way through which we can reset all the filters on clicking some button in real time (without reloading the page)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this way:

```
<button class="button">Clear</button>
```

and

```
$(function() {
    $('.button').on(function() {
        $('._filterText').val('').trigger('change');
    });
});
```

Where **.button** your clear-button class.

Answer (score 0):

All the input boxes for that filter seem to use this class... `_filterText`... so I guess you could try something like:

```
<button id="ID_of_button" name="ID_of_button" type="button">Clear Stuff!</button>  

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {  

   $("#ID_of_button").on('click',function(){  
      $('._filterText').prop("value", "");  
   });

});

</script>
```